# How do I use AppEngine and Search API to search by the DocId?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

I need to search by DocId because I have files in Drive that I am also searching, and need to merge the results. I also need to limit the results by other fields. I tried this query:

```
INFO: Searching with query:  DocId:(4842249208725504 5405199162146816 5510752278413312 5581121022590976 5827411627212800)
```

However it found 0 results even though they exist. I also tried `doc_id` and `id`.

```
    log.info("Searching with query: " + q);
    try {
        Results<ScoredDocument> results = getIndex().search(q);
```

I will also need to filter by other fields, ex:

```
DocId:(123456789) year:(2012)
```

The other fields work during searching, but not DocId. In the Admin interface, it shows DocId as being one of the fields! `http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/search?subsection=searchIndex...`

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside each document have an atom field named `docId` and in that field pass in the doc id. Then you can do a search per normal (as you suggested).

Here is a quote from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/#Java_Documents_and_fields)

> While it is convenient to create readable, meaningful unique document
>   identifiers, you cannot include the doc_id in a search. Consider this
>   scenario: You have an index with documents that represent parts, using
>   the part's serial number as the doc_id. It will be very efficient to
>   retrieve the document for any single part, but it will be impossible
>   to search for a range of serial numbers along with other field values,
>   such as purchase date. Storing the serial number in an atom field
>   solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the doc ID in advance, rather then searching for it why not just get it directly?

> doc = index.get("AZ125")

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Retrieving_documents_by_doc_ids

Comment: Because I need to do a query to limit the results of many docs. For example, I need to query where `year = 2012` or `country=Germany` for only a certain set of docs. If I used index.get(), I would have to load each doc one at a time and do a manual comparison. There are a half-dozen fields I need to search. Using index.get() will completely bypass the Search API, and then what's the point?